# foreach, dopar write to same data.table

Tags: r, foreach, data.table

I have a function which do a calculation and I want to add the result to a data.table

```
library(data.table)
library(doParallel)


data.table1 <- data.table( row_number = 1:10)


test_function <- function(input){
  data.table1[input$row_number, test:=(input$row_number^2)]
}
```

The following adds the column test as I want to data.table1

```
myCluster <- makeCluster(3, # number of cores to use
                         type = "PSOCK") # type of cluster
registerDoParallel(myCluster)

foreach(j = 1:nrow(data.table1), .packages=c("data.table","doParallel")) %do% {
  test_function(data.table1[j,])
}
stopCluster(myCluster)
```

However when I try to use dopar instead the column test doesn´t appear, I also dont get any error message

```
myCluster <- makeCluster(3, # number of cores to use
                     type = "PSOCK") # type of cluster
registerDoParallel(myCluster)

foreach(j = 1:nrow(data.table1), .packages=c("data.table","doParallel")) %dopar% {
  test_function(data.table1[j,])
}
stopCluster(myCluster)
```

Comment: When using parallelism, `data.table1` is copied to each cluster so that you modify a copy, not the original dataset. Moreover, be aware that `foreach` returns something. See for example [my tutorial on foreach](https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/).

Comment: So it isn´t posible to write to the original dataset using parallelism?

Comment: No, because the data.table is not shared between processes.

Comment: Is it posible to send batches of the input data and put it together later?

Comment: Hi , can I use the FBM() function in any way from bigstatsr described in your tutorial

Comment: The easiest solution would be that each process returns part of your new vector (foreach is perfect for that) and then you combine those parts and assign them to your data.table.

Comment: Thank you Prive, it worked :) I have a pretty slow computer with 3 cores, is it posible to get more cores or computerpower withpout to buy a new computer?

Comment: Don't know, sorry.